# Chopping Paths in C

Tags: c, string, filepath

I want to preface this by saying that I've done very little programming in C, so I'd prefer to know why a given solution works rather than just what it is.

I'm trying to write a function which will take a pathname, and return a pathname to a different file in the same directory.

```
  "/example/directory/with/image.png" => "/example/directory/with/thumbnail.png"
```

What I've tried after reading up on example uses of `realpath` and `dirname` (I'm working on Linux; if there's a cross-platform equivalent, let me know) is:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *chop_path(char *orig) {
  char buf[PATH_MAX + 1];
  char *res, *dname, *thumb;

  res = realpath(orig, buf);
  if (res) {
    dname = dirname(res);
    thumb = strcat(dname, "/thumbnail.png");
    return thumb;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling it seems to work, but running the program with

```
int main(void) {
  char *res = chop_path("original.png");
  if (res) {
    printf("Resulting pathname: %s", res);
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

gives me a segfault. Any hints?

Comment: You shouldn't allow your ``chop_path`` function to not return a value (are you getting a warning on that?)  Add a return 0; at the end of the function.

Comment: @jmquigley - Added. No warning about it; the only one I got was about a missing cast on the `dname=dirname(res)` line.

Comment: What distribution of linux and version of gcc are you using?  I'm using FreeBSD and dirname is in a different header (I was able to compile/run your code in gcc 4.2.1 after adding Ernest Friedman-Hill's suggestion, fixing the return and adding the required header for dirname in FreeBSD).

Comment: @jmquigley - I'm running gcc 4.6.2 in Debian wheezy. And... <facepalm /> adding `#include <libgen.h>` gets it working on existing files.

Comment: That's the header I'm using too.  I was going to tell you to check the manpage for dirname next to make sure you had the correct include, heh.

Comment: Yeah, I was just finding something similar. I get the warning without including `libgen.h`, but the program still works. Need to track this down...

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, it could be the implicit declaration. `dirname` isn't declared in any other header, so the `int to pointer` warning means that the implicit declaration is no good. @Inaimathi, do you have a 64-bit system? The segfault could come from converting the presumed 32-bit int return value to 64 bits for a pointer.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill - Yup; I'm running the amd64 version of wheezy on a core i3. I'm not sure how that makes a difference though, if the main problem is a missing header file.

Comment: I think the issue is that C assumes a function returns int, in the absence of any other information. Without the header, that's the assumption here. On a 32-bit machine, the conversion would (in general) always succeed. But on a 64-bit machine an `int` is 32 bits and a pointer is 64, and so the conversion can fail to produce the proper result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem I see is the signature of your `chop_path` routine; it should be

```
char *chop_path(char *orig) {
```

Your version has a missing `*`. That makes an enormous difference actually; without the `*`, you're effectively telling `dirname` and `realpath` to interpret the character code of the first character in your argument string as the numerical address (i.e., a pointer to) the path. That's going to point into  a location in low memory that you definitely have not allocated; trying to use it results in that "segmentation fault" error, which means, effectively, that you're trying to touch memory you're not allowed to.

The other issue turned out to be that the `dirname()` function is declared in `libgen.h`, which you weren't including. If you don't include that header, the compiler assumes `dirname()` returns `int` instead of a pointer, and on a 64-bit architecture, the 64-bit return value from the function gets chopped down to 32 bits, a bad pointer is assigned to `dname`, and that's going to cause your seg fault right there.

Comment: Why is a string literal implicitly convertible to a `char`?

Comment: Edited my original to reflect your suggestion. Adding the `*` doesn't get rid of the segfault though.

Comment: In classic C, almost *anything* is implicitly convertible to an `int`. A pointer, a character, a boolean expression (well, those are *natively* `int`, but you get the idea.) As a result, you end up being able to pass pretty much anything as pretty much anything, and there's an implicit conversion through `int` that makes it work. Many compilers will warn about some of the worst conversions, but they're not errors. Modern versions of C, and C's pickier cousin C++, are much better about this.

Comment: @Inaimathi -- I don't get a segfault when  run your program; indeed, I don't get anything at all. If, on the other hand, I change the argument in `main` to be the full path of an actual file on my system, then it works as expected (Mac OS X, gcc 4.0.1.) Now, strangely, I get a warning the assignment to `dname` when I compile about making a pointer of an integer, and I can't explain that one. Do you see any warnings when you compile?

Comment: Yes; I get the same warning about the `dname` assignment at compile time. It honestly doesn't work though (When I try it with a nonexistent file, nothing happens. When I try it with an existing file, it segfaults).

Comment: The warning was (as warnings often are!) a good clue. Sounds like you're in business now!

Comment: Yup :) Add the note about `libgen.h` to your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `dirname`, `realpath`, unwanted string buffer and string operations, etc - you can do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define FILE_MAX 100

void chop_path(char path_name[], char new_file[]) {
    int len = strlen(path_name);
    int i;

    for (i=len-1; i>0 ; i--) {
        if (path_name[i] == '/') {
            strcpy(path_name+i+1, new_file);
            break;
        }   
    }   

    return;
}

int main(void) {
    char path[PATH_MAX + 1] = "/this/is/a/path/filename.c";
    char new_file[FILE_MAX] = "newfilename.txt";

    printf("old : %s \n", path);
    chop_path(path, new_file);
    printf("new : %s \n", path);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc path.c 
$ ./a.out 
old : /this/is/a/path/filename.c 
new : /this/is/a/path/newfilename.txt 
$
```

Comment: I don't mind breaking the path string manually, but I would prefer not to use a procedure that relies on side effect. Confirmed that this works though; I may end up using in the end.